# A restricted form of the inner model hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, large-cardinals

*Previously [asked and bountied at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4318935/28111), with slight difference. To keep things relatively simple I'm presenting a somewhat-butchered version of the IMH; for more details, see [S.-D. Friedman, **Internal consistency and the inner model hypothesis**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4093051?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). Throughout, "ctm" means "countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$," an inner model of a ctm $\mathcal{A}$ is a ctm $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ with the same ordinals, and ctms are compatible iff they are each inner models of some single ctm.*

---

Given a class $\mathbb{K}$ of ctms, say that a ctm $\mathcal{M}\in\mathbb{K}$ **satisfies the $\mathbb{K}$-IMH** iff for every first-order sentence $\varphi$ and every ctm $\mathcal{A}\in\mathbb{K}$ which satisfies $\varphi$ and is compatible with $\mathcal{M}$ there is an inner model $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ with $\mathcal{B}\in\mathbb{K}$ and $\mathcal{B}\models\varphi$. Intuitively, anything which holds in an inner model of an outer model of $\mathcal{M}$ already holds in some inner model of $\mathcal{M}$ after we appropriately restrict attention to models in $\mathbb{K}$. The classical IMH corresponds to $\mathbb{K}$ = $\{$all ctms$\}$ - call this "$\mathbb{A}$" for "all."

I'm curious about what happens if we shift from $\mathbb{A}$ to the set of ctms $\mathbb{T}$ which don't "break" when equipped with their own elementary diagram. To be precise, suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a ctm. Via any of the usual coding mechanisms, let $T\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ code the full elementary diagram of $\mathcal{M}$. Then $\mathcal{M}\in\mathbb{T}$ iff the expansion $(\mathcal{M},T)$ satisfies the Separation and Replacement schemes in the language expanded to include a predicate for $T$. If I have my jargon right, $\mathbb{T}$ is the set of ctms whose unique *total satisfaction class* is *amenable* (but the literature I could find on satisfaction classes doesn't seem relevant to this particular question).

My question, then, is:

> What can we say about models satisfying the $\mathbb{T}$-IMH?

Specifically (and under reasonable hypotheses as appropriate):

- Are there models satisfying the $\mathbb{T}$-IMH which have inaccessible cardinals?
- Are there models satisfying the $\mathbb{T}$-IMH with real parameters (that is, we allow $\varphi$ to contain parameters from $\mathbb{R}\cap M$)?

A negative answer to each question for the $\mathbb{A}$-IMH follows from the fact *(Beller-David, see Friedman's above-linked paper)* that every ctm $\mathcal{A}$ has an outer model $\mathcal{B}$ with a real $r\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $L_\alpha[r]\not\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ for every $\alpha\in\mathsf{Ord}^\mathcal{B}$. However, models with such "weird" reals can't lie in $\mathbb{T}$, roughly since the presence of such a real indicates internally that the model "ought to be" countable.